# How long do Bloodhound's clues stay visible?

Tags: apex-legends

In Apex, character Bloodhound has passive ability to see "clues" - icons, indicating certain actions performed by enemy.

Icons have fading outlines, which may indicate, how long ago action was performed. But it is fairly hard to estimate, when this icon has appeared, without knowing how long it exists in the first place.

So, how long such icon actually stays visible?

Comment: Just a note, if you look at the clue it will say something like "X seconds ago"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When looking at clues, you will notice they have a timer that counts up.  This timer counts up to 60 seconds.  Thus clues only remain for 60 seconds.  Additionally, the clue icons have an animation around the border of them that also indicate how old the clue is.

Another [source](https://rankedboost.com/apex-legends/bloodhound/) that indicates this:

> Tracks left behind by enemy players only last 60 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Clues remain visible for 60 seconds.